# get complete path of Image in Serializer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, paperclip

I am uploading images with Paperclip in my rails App. For API I want to return full path image through serializer like

```
https://my_server_address/system/.../my_image.jpg
```

I find a way for this by writing this in serializer

```
class EmployeeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :employee_image
  def employee_image
    HOST+ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path(object.employee_image.url(:medium))
  end
end
```

where I have to set `HOST` through `environment variable` on server and append image path with this. it gives me the full path.

But still there is another issue, I am using `Apartment` gem for **Database multi-tenancy for Rack (and Rails) applications**

So for each company there a new database as well as different path for server.

Like for Company named Lahore, server URL is

```
https://Lahore.my_server_address
```

and Company named Karachi, server URL is

```
https://Karachi.my_server_address
```

So in this scenario, can't set HOST.

**NOTE: request is not accessible in Serializer**

So, what approach, I can use to handle this?